# No element affected by SQL statement

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, uitableview, sql-delete

I would like to know how could I identify if there is no element affected by an SQL statement (specifically a Delete). I have the next function associated to a button that erases the content of an UITableView, the parameter i give to it (nombre) it`s a UITextField.text element. Any further information would be given

```
#import "SD9ProxyBD.h"
#include <sqlite3.h>

@implementation SD9ProxyBD

-(NSMutableArray *)nombres{
sqlite3 *laBd;
sqlite3_stmt *consultaPreparada;
const char *consulta="Select nombre from informacion";
NSString *ruta=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mibd"];
sqlite3_open([ruta UTF8String], &laBd);
sqlite3_prepare(laBd,consulta,-1,&consultaPreparada,NULL);
NSMutableArray *resultados=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
while (sqlite3_step(consultaPreparada)==SQLITE_ROW) {
    [resultados addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(consultaPreparada,0)]];

 }
sqlite3_close(laBd);
return resultados;
}

-(void)insertarNombre:(NSString *)nombre{
sqlite3 *laBd;
sqlite3_stmt *consultaPreparada;
const char *consulta="Insert into informacion(nombre) values(?)";
NSString *ruta=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mibd"];
sqlite3_open([ruta UTF8String], &laBd);
sqlite3_prepare(laBd,consulta,-1,&consultaPreparada,NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(consultaPreparada,1,[nombre UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_step(consultaPreparada);
sqlite3_finalize(consultaPreparada);
sqlite3_close(laBd);
}

-(void)eliminarNombre:(NSString *)nombre{
sqlite3 *laBd;
sqlite3_stmt *consultaPreparada;
const char *consulta="Delete from informacion where nombre=?";
NSString *ruta=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mibd"];
sqlite3_open([ruta UTF8String], &laBd);
sqlite3_prepare(laBd,consulta,-1,&consultaPreparada,NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(consultaPreparada,1,[nombre UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_step(consultaPreparada);
sqlite3_finalize(consultaPreparada);
sqlite3_close(laBd);
}

@end
```

And here is the code of the button:

```
- (IBAction)eliminar:(id)sender {
[self.texto resignFirstResponder];
[self.proxyBD eliminarNombre:self.texto.text];
[self.tabla reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Maybe there's nothing to delete?

Comment: In fact there is nothing to delete, but i would like to know when that happens and display an UIAlertView

Comment: (You've given us almost nothing to work with.)

Comment: Sorry I`ll edit it and add the whole code

Comment: You could check the return codes.  (I know that sounds rash, but I'm that kind of wild and crazy guy.)

Comment: The return codes from the 6 sqlite3 statements above, for starters.

Comment: And we really need to see the table schema.

Comment: Like you pointed out i am really starter at Objective C and XCode, how could i get those return codes?

Comment: `int returnCode = sqlite3_open([ruta UTF8String], &laBd);`  And if `returnCode` is not an expected value (see the list of possible values [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)), then use `sqlite3_errmsg` to display detailed error info:  `NSLog(@"SQLite error %d, errmsg = %s", returnCode, sqlite3_errmsg(laBd));`.

Comment: i think i know what you mean. You mean errors code from sqlite returned at execution time. I think you are not understanding me. I got no errors with the code I have posted, but i would like to know that the text I am trying to erase DOESN´T EXIST AT THE DATABASE, and then doing the proper Alert for that. Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Perhaps you should refer to [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html).

Comment: The return code is 0, even if I try to erase an element that doesn´t exist at DB. So there is no sqlite3_errmsg to display

Comment: Did you refer to [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html)?

Comment: I think that´s the exact answer to my problem. Let me code it out

Comment: Just as I thought it solved my problem. Thank you so much for all the help and patience. I am giving you the best answer

Comment: mmmmm you didn´t put one. That´s weird and funny. Thank you anyway